# Backup an Oracle database to NAS

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, rman

I have an Oracle database (11.2.0.4) on Oracle Linux 6.7.

I want to backup this database with rman to a folder on a NAS (network attach storage).

How can I do this?

Comment: If you can see the NAS (presumably as some mount point), why not just use usual backup procedures?

Answer (score 1):

Is quite simple. Make sure that oracle can write on a folder on the NAS and run the following RMAN job:

```
run
{
  CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO disk;
  BACKUP FULL DATABASE INCLUDE CURRENT CONTROLFILE FORMAT '<NAS-directory>/<some-name>_%d_F_%T_%s';
}
```